# Daylight Saving Time (DST) in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I'm creating a web application using cakephp 1.2.6. There is a functionality that I need to save the time that user is entered in GMT format. I'm using below method to do this.

```
function convertDateTimeToGMT($dateTimeStr,$fromTimeZone, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s') {
    if (empty($dateTimeStr))
    return $dateTimeStr;
    else if (empty($fromTimeZone))
    return $dateTimeStr;
    else {
        // Inverse the + or minus. Decimal value should be passed
        //$timeHelper = new TimeHelper();
        $newTZ = -1 * $fromTimeZone;
        return $this->format($format, $dateTimeStr, null, $newTZ) ;
    }
}


function format($format = 'd-m-Y', $date, $invalid = false, $userOffset = null) {
    $date = $this->fromString($date, $userOffset);
    if ($date === false && $invalid !== false) {
        return $invalid;
    }
    return date($format, $date);
}

function fromString($dateString, $userOffset = null) {
    if (empty($dateString)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (is_int($dateString) || is_numeric($dateString)) {
        $date = intval($dateString);
    } else {
        $date = strtotime($dateString);
    }
    if ($userOffset !== null) {
        return $this->convert($date, $userOffset);
    }
    return $date;
}

function convert($serverTime, $userOffset) {
    $serverOffset = $this->serverOffset();
    $gmtTime = $serverTime - $serverOffset;
    $userTime = $gmtTime + $userOffset * (60*60);
    return $userTime;
}
```

`convertDateTimeToGMT($dateTimeStr,$fromTimeZone, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')` is the method that I'm calling in my code to pass the date time and time zone. I have a combo box of time zones and if user select time zone as "Pacific" it will pass the -8 as the value of `$fromTimeZone`. But because of the DST this can be changed.

So is there any way in cakephp  to find the up to date time zone values automatically and convert the time to GMT?

Comment: That's why only asking the user for the GMT offset is not good enough. You need to ask him for his *timezone*.

Comment: User selects his/her time zone from the drop down. But how can I get the GMT time with DST from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you know the timezone of the user you can get its offset as follows:

```
$est_tz = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$d = new DateTime("now", $est_tz);
$offset = $est_tz->getOffset($d);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. Finally I was able to find the solution using date('O') function in php